# How to get the length of data in a column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query in SQL and I want to check the length of data in a column. Is there any inbuilt function for that?

Comment: Your question is not about TOAD, but about SQL.

Answer (score 4):

you can use LEN() or LENGTH() inbuilt function as a example

SELECT LENGTH(column_name) FROM table_name

Try this one & tell if it's working or not?

Comment: Hi PravinG, Len is not working.. however i tried length() and its working perfect. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: it may be because , you are using Toad, I use normally  Mysql database and forMYsql LEN()works for me... ok gud..